# How to convert String to number in Java?

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion

I have a parameter which is obtained as a string

```
String Dept_ID[] = request.getParameterValues("dept_id"))
```

in jsp. I have to insert the string in the db whose  type is numeric

```
@DEPT_ID NUMERIC(10,0)).
```

How to perform the conversion?

Answer (score 5):

Your code is receiving an *array* of strings. You can convert an entry from the array into a number using [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) or [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) as appropriate.

For example:

```
String Dept_ID[] = request.getParameterValues("dept_id"));
int[] ids = null;
if (Dept_ID != null) {
    ids = new int[Dept_ID.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < Dept_ID.length; ++index) {
        ids[index] = Integer.parseInt(Dept_ID[index]);
    }
}
```

If the number uses a different radix (number base) than 10, you can supply the radix as a second arg (see the links for details).

Comment: I did exactly the same thing u hv typed in the code but its throwing an exception :- Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: @rams: The code you showed shouldn't do anything like that. [`ServletRequest#getParameterValues`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) doesn't have anything to do with databases. (And if `request` isn't a `ServletRequest` or a subclass of it, you **really** need to say that, as that's the only reasonable assumption we could make.)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but it doesn't take into account what happens when your getting letters as input that can't be converted. You wanna use a try and catch method for that part if you ask me.

Something like (assuming your using the code above):

```
String Dept_ID[] = request.getParameterValues("dept_id"));
int[] ids = null;

if (Dept_ID != null) {
    ids = new int[Dept_ID.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < Dept_ID.length; index++) {
        try {
            ids[index] = Integer.parseInt(Dept_ID[index]);
        }
        catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid crap.");
        }
    }
}
```

Also notice that I put the ++index part the other way around to index++, if you don't do this you will keep missing the first index in the array all the time.